# creating vertical accordian menu using angularjs

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I want to make a vertical accordion menu using angularjs + jquery + css plz anyone can help me with the code how to do it .how can I bind these jquery function with angularjs . thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far??? Any code?? Please show it, we won't script it for you from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using angular-ui.

You have to spend some time here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion